# Disconcerting security message in tangerine bank app, should i be concerned?

Tags: security

Using a One Plus Three,  not rooted.

I get this popup when i start up the Tangerine banking app:

They recently updated the app and it wasn't doing this before

[image: security warning]

Comment: I'd contact the dev asking how they define "unauthorized modifications" here. It *could* be something wrong – but it could also be simply due to the fact the 1+ runs a specific "own OS" (either CyanogenOS or their own OxygenOS), in which case the devs would need to adjust their checks.

Comment: thanks @Izzy, I've contacted them, we'll see if they can shed some light on the situation

Comment: Anytime. Please don't forget to report back in case you get a useful answer :)